# Monkey patching ActiveStorage::Attachment gets lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, monkeypatching, rails-activestorage

So I decided to add an `url` attr_accessor to ActiveStorage::Attachment objects.

In *development* the patch holds for a while until it seems to "have been lost". Meaning it works for few minutes, then it does not work anymore. Then I need to restart the server in order to get the patch applied again. I believe I am not patching correctly and I would need advises in that mater.

---

Here is what I tried:

**lib/ext/active_storage/attachment.rb**

First try :

```
module ActiveStorageUrl
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :url
  end
end

ActiveStorage::Attachment.send :include, ActiveStorageUrl
```

Second try

```
class ActiveStorage::Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :url
end
```

---

And by the way in both case it's loaded with this:

**config/initializers/monkey_patches.rb**

```
require 'ext/active_storage/attachment'
```

---

So when it work I have no error message, but after a while the patch "diseapear" (lacking better terms), and I get the following error, telling me  my attr_accessor is not there anymore. Rails must have reloaded ActiveStorage classes and my patch is lost.

```
Module::DelegationError in Products#images
url delegated to blob, but blob is nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably losing your monkey patch because the code gets reloaded and your **ext/active_storage/attachment** isn't re-required.

You can tell Rails to run a callback at startup and every time code is reloaded like this.

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  require 'ext/active_storage/attachment'
end
```

Comment: Seems to be the method I needed to know about. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I placed my `ActiveStorage::Attachment`MonkeyPatch in **/app/models/active_storage/**
I've added a callback to get informed if the Attachment has changed. It works fine, all the time.

Maybe this is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to have to do with `delegate_missing_to`, e.g.

```
delegate_missing_to :blob
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/attachment.rb#L14

Going to [where it's defined](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb#L278):

Anyway it might have to do with how `attr_accessor` works, I would try:

```rb
def url
  @url
end

def url=(url)
  @url = url
end
```

Instead of `attr_accessor` (which is a C function actually).

Otherwise a really really hacky way to solve this would be to check for `ActiveStorage::Attachment.instance_methods.include?(:url)` and monkey patch / include / prepend when not present.

Comment: Ok I defined geter and setter instead of `attr_accessor`. Will see how it goes. Thanks